# Sorting Dynamically generated HTML Table

Tags: sorting

I am generating a dynamic HTML table string and displaying inside a div. I am assigning ID and runat server in that string. eg.

`string s="<table id='tblAll' runat='server'></table>"`.

This string is generated on some different page, and its passed as XmlhttpResponseText

I want to apply sorting on this table, It would be great if any one can help me out. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery **[tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)** plugin

Comment: ya but how?? 
i can not assign the id, as its in string

$("#HTMLTableName").tablesorter();

its not able to find that HTML Table ID

Comment: After inserting the object to the DOM you can bind it. I am not sure whether tablesorter will work for dynamically generated objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin, and instead of selecting the table via it's Id, you can select it via the containing div and a child selector:

```
$("div#container table").tablesorter();
```